# Getting Error when the filename contains Space

Tags: xcode, shell

I am having a filename with space. My Filename is (7 Bridges.app.dSYM)

I am printing the location of the file.
echo $dsymlocation

/Users/aa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/bridges2-ekucwkrbbusrvsdxyegvpkdkiitj/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/7\ Bridges.app.dSYM

If i give the location of the file directly as input to the below command, it is working. 
dwarfdump --debug-pubnames /Users/aa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/bridges2-ekucwkrbbusrvsdxyegvpkdkiitj/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/7\ Bridges.app.dSYM

But if i give the variable name containing the file location, it is not working 
dwarfdump --debug-pubnames "$dsymlocation"

It is showing the error as 
unable to open '/Users/aa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/bridges2-ekucwkrbbusrvsdxyegvpkdkiitj/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/7\ Bridges.app.dSYM': No such file or directory

Can anyone help to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error message complains about a file named `7\ Bridges.app.dSYM`, while the file is, according to what you say, `7 Bridges.app.dSYM`. It looks like the content of the variable *dsymlocation* contains a backslash. We can see the backslash also, when you do the `echo $dsymlocation`.